# android how to check app is downloaded from (Play store/android market )or( bluetooth/other )

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to validate on My app ABCD. I have added functionality in my app to send it  to other device. I can send my installed app ABCD form my device to other device via Bluetooth.
Now , I want to create check .

```
if(isFromPlayStore){
    // always valid downloaded from play store
}else{
    // trial version expired in 30 day
}
```

Comment: Please have a look at [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html). This might help you in getting some idea.